# How to update database via migrations when I have two (or more) config files with different database connections?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, configuration

First of all, it's nothing important, it's just for learning.

I have two config files `appsettings.Development.json` and `appsettings.Staging.json`.

The first one has the connection string:
`"DatabaseConnection": "Data Source=BlaBla;Initial Catalog=MyDatabse-DEV;Integrated Security = True;"`
and the second
`"DatabaseConnection": "Data Source=BlaBla;Initial Catalog=MyDatabse-STG;Integrated Security = True;"`.

I want to apply the migrations for the Staging environment (so the file `appsettings.Staging.json` should be used). I already declared an environment variable named `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` with value "Staging".

In `Startup.cs` I have the following code:

```
 var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
              .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
              .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
              .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
              .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            configuration = builder.Build();
```

The `env.EnvironmentName`'s value is always "Development" no matter what I do.

### Solution

Replace the `env.EnvironmentName` variable with "Staging" - problem solved! Nothing burning. But for learning: is there an intelligent way to do this. What if, by mistake, I write "Production" instead of "Staging"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch between environments with the following commands:

```
$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Local"
$env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"
$env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Release"
```

These commmands go in your cli from visual studio

then with the following commands you can update your database en select the right context.

```
Add-Migration -Context:ApplicationDbContext xxxxxx
Update-Database -Context:ApplicationDbContext
```